# VSCode Typescript intellisense not work.. why?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

- Install `JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly` extension
- Add `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts", "node_modules", "vendor", "public"],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

babel

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    ["@babel/preset-typescript", { "allExtensions": true, "isTSX": true }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "inline-react-svg",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }]
  ]
}
```

No VSCode Typescript intellisense. Why?

Comment: Let's start write TS the code, and `Typescript intellisense` will suggests for you typehint, keyword....

Comment: I've updated to nightly build and it works now ‍♂️